# Robolectric test android hardware?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Hi i am trying to test the nfc adapter via robolectric 2.4 but i keep getting the following error:

```
WARNING: unknown service nfc
```

It fails when i execute the code below:

```
 NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) context.getSystemService(context.NFC_SERVICE);
        NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
```

Is it not possible to test these somehow? i am trying to get the nfc adapter and checking what the nfc settings is on my unit tests but it crashes and fails with a nullpointer with the given error

Comment: There is Robolectric 3 is released and 3.1 is in RC state

Comment: I see that it should work with 3.1-rc1

Comment: cant use 3.1 i am stuck with using 3

Comment: What do you mean? It is available already in maven repo